# Android ViewPager in ViewPager only one child has data

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I know there is a lot of different issues about PageViewers but I can't find solution to my problem.
 The problem is that in my app i have one `PageView`in another lets say that in `PageView`A i have `PageView` B. In A i keep some informations in `TextViews` and B. B keeps `ImageView` and should display images for my fragments. A has few pages and on every page I have right data on `TextViews` but only one(the first visible one) contains images. When i switch pages none of B `ViewPager` have images but have right `TextViews`.

Adapter for A and `getFragments()` method:

```
class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
          private List<Fragment> pages;
          public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
            super(fm);
            this.pages = fragments;
          }
          @Override 
          public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return this.pages.get(position);


          }
          @Override
          public int getCount() {
           return this.pages.size();

          }
        }
    private ArrayList<Fragment> getFragments(){
          ArrayList<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
          for(int i=0;i<diary.getList().get(index).events.size();i++){
          fList.add(EventPageFragment.newInstance("",index,i));
          }
          return fList;
        }
```

CreateView and adapter in `EventPageFragment`:

```
 @Override

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,

   Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     String message = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
       int index = getArguments().getInt(INDEX);
        int eventIndex = getArguments().getInt(EVENT);

   View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_eventview, container, false);
   TextView title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.event_past_title);
   TextView date = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.event_past_date);
   TextView description = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.event_past_desc);
   title.bringToFront();
   images = getFragments(index,eventIndex);
   pager = (ViewPager)v.findViewById(R.id.event_pager);
   pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getFragmentManager(),images);
   pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
    pageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    pager.invalidate();

   title.setText(diary.getList().get(index).events.get(eventIndex).getTitle());
   date.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.date)+": "+diary.getList().get(index).events.get(eventIndex).getDate()[0]+"/"+
           diary.getList().get(index).events.get(eventIndex).getDate()[1]+"/"+
                   diary.getList().get(index).events.get(eventIndex).getDate()[2]);
   description.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.description)+": "+diary.getList().get(index).events.get(eventIndex).getDescription());


   return v;

 }

 class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
      private List<Fragment> images;
      public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.images = fragments;
      }
      @Override 
      public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.images.get(position);
      }
      @Override
      public int getCount() {
        return this.images.size();
      }
    }

private ArrayList<Fragment> getFragments(int index, int event){
     ArrayList<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
     for(int i=0;i<diary.getList().get(index).events.get(event).photoReference.size();i++){
         fList.add(PhotoFragment.newInstance("",index,event,i));

     }
      return fList;

    }
```

And finally PhotoFragment that represents images in B:

```
 public static final PhotoFragment newInstance(String message, int personIndex, int eventIndex, int photoIndex)

 {

     PhotoFragment f = new PhotoFragment();

   Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);
   bdl.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
   bdl.putInt(INDEX, personIndex);
   bdl.putInt(EVENT, eventIndex);
   bdl.putInt(PHOTO, photoIndex);
   f.setArguments(bdl);

   return f;

 }



 @Override

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,

   Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   String message = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
  int index = getArguments().getInt(INDEX);
  int eventIndex = getArguments().getInt(EVENT);
  int photoIndex = getArguments().getInt(PHOTO);
   View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_photo_fragment, container, false);

   ImageView image = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.event_photo_image);

          image.setImageBitmap(PhotoManager.decodeFile(diary.getList().get(index).events.get(eventIndex).photoReference.get(photoIndex),300));


   return v;

 }

}
```

I have no idea why only one EventPage loads images from `PhotoFragment`

Comment: Can you try to change FragmentPagerAdapter  to FragmentStatePagerAdapter. Let's see if that works.

Comment: 0 changes ;( still the same problem